# How to parse json with a parent class and get the desired child class from it?

Tags: java

The situation is like this:
I get a json that can be one of several classes. All possible classes are combined by one parent.

```
public class Response implements Serializable {}
```

I would like to do it beautifully something like:

```
Response response = GSON.fromJson(content, Response.class);
RegisterPreAuthResponse registerPreAuth = (RegisterPreAuthResponse) response;
```

Not of course I can't do that. Since I get a ClassCastException
I had an option to make a loop with ignoring ClassCastException and iterating over the children to define the class.
Or make a JSONObject and define the fields that came in and then create a class.
But I would like to find the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GSON does not know anything about java types, it only tries to parse input string and map it to class you have requested.
If you want something like dynamic mappings it will be ugly since you will have to obtain information what kind of response it is. For example have `"class" : "packet.Class"` in your response body / headers.
But this is really bad practice and should be avoided.

I see that you have content (JSON response) from some service so maybe you can determine in your code type of response by kind of service you have called?